# given $a_{n+1}=2a_n^2-1$ ($a_1>1$) prove that infinite product $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\dfrac{1}{a_k}\right)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that :

$$a_1>1$$
$$a_{n+1}=2a_n^2-1$$

prove that the infinite product

$$P_n:=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\dfrac{1}{a_k}\right)$$

converges to

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{a_1+1}{a_1-1}}$$

My try :

the recurrence relation along with the fact that $a_1>1$ (yielding $a_n>1$) suggests introducing

$$a_n = \cosh(b_n)$$

let's first re-write the product $P_n$ as

$$P_n=2^{n-1}(1+a_1)\times \dfrac{Q_n}{a_n}$$

where

$$Q_n:= \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k$$ ($n\ge 2$)(with usual product convention $Q_1:=1$)

Now the recurrence relation gives for positive natural $k$

$$a_{k+1}=\cosh(2b_k)$$

then the injectivity of $\cosh$ over positives, along with the recurrence relation and finite descending induction gives for positive natural $n$

$$a_k=\cosh\left( \dfrac{b_n}{2^k} \right)$$ (for $k$ between $1$ and $n$)

$$Q_n:= \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \cosh\left(b_n/2^k\right)$$

this product is known to be simplifiable when multiplying it by $\sinh\left(\dfrac{b_n}{2^{n-1}}\right)$ , turning into

$$Q_n=\dfrac{\sinh(b_n)}{2^{n-1}\sinh\left(\dfrac{b_n}{2^{n-1}}\right)}$$

Combining the previous facts, we get :

$$P_n=\dfrac{\sinh(b_n)}{\sinh\left(\dfrac{b_n}{2^{n-1}}\right)} \times \dfrac{1+a_1}{a_n}$$

Now it seems that we should find an equivalent of $a_n$, thing that I'm stuck with .

$(a_n)$ is strictly increasing thus bounded below by $a_1>1$ and candidates to be finite limits of it are $1$ and $-\dfrac 1 2$  thus it diverges to $+\infty$.

I can't continue from here.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got pretty close to the answer. Note that $b_n = 2^{n-1} b_1$. Thus,
\begin{align}
  P_n = \dfrac{\sinh(2^{n-1}b_1)}{\sinh\left(b_1\right)} \dfrac{a_1+1}{\cosh(2^{n-1}b_1)} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+1}{\sinh(b_1)} = \frac{a_1+1}{\sqrt{a_1^2-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{a_1+1}{a_1-1}}.
\end{align}